# Using ads in PhoneGap iPhone app

Tags: iphone, native, cordova, ads

Does anyone have any insight, experience/links they can point me to for adding ads to an app I'm building on the PhoneGap platform?

I've been searching and not a lot of information out there.  Thought I'd ask.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on which platform you are looking for, there are different implementations. You can go with a purely web-based approach (integrating google Ads, for example). Given you tagged it with iPhone, I guess you are looking for an iOS solution?

If so, check out the [AdPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/AdPlugin) available on GitHub. It is a bit of objective C and a bit of JavaScript that allows you to integrate native iAds into your phonegap-iphone app.